# Creating Thumbnail of Video from screenshot using Fluent FFMPEG in Node JS

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I am using `Node JS` to create API and have used `Fluent- FFMPEG` to take the screenshot once the video is uploaded. I am getting the below error. I found many answers for this error but none worked.`Fluent-ffmpeg` is installed. I have attached the package.json sample code, too. Also the snippet of the ffmpeg code.

Do I have to install `ffmpeg` on my windows to make this api to work ? do I have to set any environment variables ?

**Error**

```
events.js:173
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Cannot find ffprobe
at D:\project\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\ffprobe.js:145:31
at D:\project\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:194:9
```

**Package.json**

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-validator": "^6.6.1",
"fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2", // it has been installed
"i18n": "^0.8.4",
```

**Code**

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
await ffmpeg(getFileFromLocal)
                .screenshots({
                    count: 1,
                    filename: fileName,
                    folder: folderName
                }).on('end', async function () {
                    //further code
                })
            return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working. I was missing with 2 things.

1. `FFmpeg` is not installed. I installed from this [Link](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/). (Note: `Fluent-ffmpeg` requires `FFmpeg` to be installed in your OS. Without `FFmpeg`, `Fluent-ffmpeg` will not work.)
2. Set Environment Variable. Follow [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows) tutorial to set the environment variable.

After doing the above two task, I was successfully able to create screenshots of videos.